# Task scheduler: when awaiting in a Task.Factory.StartNew, is the thread returned to the pool?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, task, task-parallel-library

I'm implementing a worker engine with an upper limit to concurrency.  I'm using a semaphore to wait until concurrency drops below the maximum, then use `Task.Factory.StartNew` to wrap the async handler in a `try`/`catch`, with a `finally` which releases the semaphore.

I realise this creates threads on the thread pool - but my question is, when one of those task-running threads actually awaits (on a real IO call or wait handle), is the thread returned to the pool, as I'd hope it would be?

If there's a better way to implement a task scheduler with limited concurrency where the work handler is an async method (returns `Task`), I'd love to hear it too.  Or, let's say ideally, if there's a way to queue up an async method (again, it's a `Task`-returning async method) that feels less dodgy than wrapping it in a synchronous delegate and passing it to `Task.Factory.StartNew`, that would seem perfect..?

(This also makes me think that there are two kinds of parallelism here: how many tasks are being processed overall, but also how many continuations are running on different threads concurrently.  Might be cool to have configurable options for both, though not a fixed requirement..)

Edit: snippet:

```
                    concurrencySemaphore.Wait(cancelToken);
                    deferRelease = false;
                    try
                    {
                        var result = GetWorkItem();
                        if (result == null)
                        { // no work, wait for new work or exit signal
                            signal = WaitHandle.WaitAny(signals);
                            continue;
                        }

                        deferRelease = true;
                        tasks.Add(Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                        {
                            try
                            {
                                DoWorkHereAsync(result); // guess I'd think to .GetAwaiter().GetResult() here.. not run this yet
                            }
                            finally
                            {
                                concurrencySemaphore.Release();
                            }
                        }, cancelToken));
                    }
                    finally
                    {
                        if (!deferRelease)
                        {
                            concurrencySemaphore.Release();
                        }
                    }
```

Comment: Alternatively, if you are worried about concurrency limits and async, why not use TPL DataFlow instead?  It alllows you to limit each graph component and is `async/await` compatible, perfect for IO-bound calls rather than re-inventing the wheel

Comment: If your `StartNew` starts with `await semaphore.WaitAsync` - it will not hold this thread while awaiting if you mean that. And so if you queue many such tasks - it might not even create additional threads in thread pool.

Comment: I've added some code @MickyD .  I wait for the semaphore before trying to read work from the queue, and didn't think of TPL DataFlow but will take a look.. if it still looks relevant?

Comment: Thank-you for code.

Comment: @Evk My main issue is with the perceived dodgyness of wrapping an async handler in a sync delegate, only to wrap in a new task.  I think I may have missed Task.Run and the overload which seems to take an async delegate.. I guess I'd want to `async` up my wrapping task and `await` the `DoWorkHereAsync`..

Comment: With your code sample I don't see much reason to use `StartNew`. You can as well do `DoWorkHereAsync(...).ContinueWith(t => semaphore.Release())`. By the way don't forget to pass `cancelToken` to `DoWorkHereAsync`.

Comment: @Evk - the first part of the async method (the blocking part) would block any other tasks starting in parallel, wouldn't it?

Comment: What is the nature of the `DoWorkHereAsync` method? Your code should not be blocking. You can use https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.semaphoreslim.waitasync?view=netframework-4.7.1 to wait asynchronously.

Comment: Yes it will, though I rarely see or write such tasks, but in general that might be a problem indeed. If that is a concern `Task.Run(async () ...` makes some sense indeed. But probably better rewrite this using `await semaphore.WaitAsync()`, for example like answer below suggests.

Comment: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here an example of a TaskWorker, that will not produce countless worker threads.

The magic is done by awaiting `SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync()` which is an IO task (and there is no thread).

```
class TaskWorker
{
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;

    public TaskWorker(int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
    {
        if (maxDegreeOfParallelism <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDegreeOfParallelism));
        }

        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDegreeOfParallelism, maxDegreeOfParallelism);
    }

    public async Task RunAsync(Func<Task> taskFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        // No ConfigureAwait(false) here to keep the SyncContext if any
        // for the real task
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        try
        {
            await taskFactory().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release(1);
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> RunAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cancellationToken);
        try
        {
            return await taskFactory().ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
        finally
        {
            _semaphore.Release(1);
        }
    }
}
```

and a simple console app to test

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var worker = new TaskWorker(1);
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        var token = cts.Token;

        var tasks = Enumerable.Range(1, 10)
            .Select(e => worker.RunAsync(() => SomeWorkAsync(e, token), token))
            .ToArray();

        Task.WhenAll(tasks).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }

    static async Task SomeWorkAsync(int id, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Some Started {id}");
        await Task.Delay(2000, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        Console.WriteLine($"Some Finished {id}");
    }
}
```

**Update**

`TaskWorker` implementing `IDisposable`

```
class TaskWorker : IDisposable
{
    private readonly CancellationTokenSource _cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
    private readonly SemaphoreSlim _semaphore;
    private readonly int _maxDegreeOfParallelism;

    public TaskWorker(int maxDegreeOfParallelism)
    {
        if (maxDegreeOfParallelism <= 0)
        {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(maxDegreeOfParallelism));
        }

        _maxDegreeOfParallelism = maxDegreeOfParallelism;
        _semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(maxDegreeOfParallelism, maxDegreeOfParallelism);
    }

    public async Task RunAsync(Func<Task> taskFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, _cts.Token))
        {
            // No ConfigureAwait(false) here to keep the SyncContext if any
            // for the real task
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cts.Token);
            try
            {
                await taskFactory().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release(1);
            }
        }
    }

    public async Task<T> RunAsync<T>(Func<Task<T>> taskFactory, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        ThrowIfDisposed();

        using (var cts = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken, _cts.Token))
        {
            await _semaphore.WaitAsync(cts.Token);
            try
            {
                return await taskFactory().ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            finally
            {
                _semaphore.Release(1);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ThrowIfDisposed()
    {
        if (disposedValue)
        {
            throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
        }
    }

    #region IDisposable Support
    private bool disposedValue = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!disposedValue)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _cts.Cancel();
                // consume all semaphore slots
                for (int i = 0; i < _maxDegreeOfParallelism; i++)
                {
                    _semaphore.WaitAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();
                }
                _semaphore.Dispose();
                _cts.Dispose();
            }
            disposedValue = true;
        }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Ah, superb. I'll need to add something to make sure all tasks are awaited/completed, and the semaphore fully released, before disposing the Semaphore object, but I think this is a very neat and tidy solution, thanks (edit: silly me, WhenAll already does that..)

Comment: @KierenJohnstone I added a disposable TaskWorker :o)

Comment: Quick question, if the semaphore WaitAsync returns immediately, wouldn't the first (synchronous) part of the task run as blocking?

Comment: It will also blocking if you have a SyncContext - as if without the TaskWorker

Answer (score 2):

You can think that thread is returned to a `ThreadPool` even thought it is not actauly a return. The thread simply picks next queued item when async operation starts.

I would suggest you to look at `Task.Run` instead of `Task.Factory.StartNew` [Task.Run vs Task.Factory.StartNew](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2011/10/24/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/).

And also have a look at [TPL DataFlow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library). I think it will match your requirements.